# join 2 files based on fields in a columns

Tags: linux, join, awk

I´m trying to join two files that have different row and columns length and have a column which contains similar information in an unsorted way.

The files look like this:
file 1

```
ab 23 33 4 55 6 7 8 9
ab 2 3 44 5 6 7 8
ab 3 4 22 7 8 9 9 00 9
ad 2 3 4 5 4 3
ac 456 47 8 9 0 0 hh kk
af 2 dd 5 6 zz 7 8
```

file2

```
data ab 33 4 5
data ad 3 4 5 
data ac 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

expected output:

file 3

```
ab 23 33 4 55 6 7 8 9 data ab 33 4 5
ab 2 3 44 5 6 7 8 data ab 33 4 5
ab 3 4 22 7 8 9 9 00 9 data ab 33 4 5
ad 2 3 4 5 4 3 data ad 3 4 5 
ac 456 47 8 9 0 0 hh kk data ac 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Looking also other posts [How to join multiple txt files into based on column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152187/how-to-join-multiple-txt-files-into-based-on-column) [Join on first column of two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210503/join-on-first-column-of-two-files), I figured out that the best way is using

```
awk
```

I tried that:

```
awk -F "\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0; next}$1 in a {print $0, a[$2]}' file2 file1 > file3
```

The problem is that it prints just file1 and not file2.

I really do not understand where my mistake is. Any suggestion?

Thank you very much!

Comment: post the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't post the expected output, but your awk line has problem, I guess it should be:

```
awk -F "\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0; next}$1 in a {print $0, a[$1]}' file2 file1
```

I changed in last `{...}`, `a[$2] -> a[$1]`.

Comment: this is so frustrating....yes you are right! But I do not understand why. Does `a[$2]` mean "print the whole first file"?

Comment: @efrem in `NR==FNR{..}`, `$1,2,3... ` are columns from your first input file which is `file2`. in `$1 in a{...}` here, `$1,$2,$3...` are the columns from your 2nd inputfile, which is `file1`, I think you were confused by the `$x` and input files

Comment: Thank you very much. It does the job, but, as I indicated in the edited-post, something odd happens now. I do not understand why.