# awk error code for joining two files using common field

Tags: bash, awk, logic

I have two files I want to combine according with the information in the first column.

```
$ cat file1

gnl_1045_ 2 -0.74
gnl_1045_ 2 -0.74
gnl_1046_ 10 0.996904   
gnl_1046_ 10 6.904


$ cat file2

gnl_100_ 2 0.42
gnl_100_ 2 0.42
gnl_1025_ 2 0.825
gnl_1025_ 2 0.825
gnl_1046_ 7 4.598512
gnl_1046_ 7 0.4598512
```

Expected output

```
gnl_1046_ 10 0.996904   gnl_1046_ 7 4.598512    
gnl_1046_ 10 6.904   gnl_1046_ 7 0.4598512
```

Considering also my previous question ([join 2 files based on fields in a columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135990/join-2-files-based-on-fields-in-a-columns)), I was quite sure about my 'awk' code:

```
awk -F "\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next}$1 in a{print a[$1],$0}' file1 file2
```

But it does not work properly, since it print correctly 'file2' but of 'file1' it print always only the first line of the common field:

```
gnl_1046_ 10 0.996904   gnl_1046_ 7 4.598512    
gnl_1046_ 10 0.996904   gnl_1046_ 7 0.4598512
```

I do not really understand where my mistake is.
Any suggestion?
Thank you!

Comment: This is not possible. Since you are using  `$1` as index, how should `awk` know if it should take data fro first or second  `gnl_1046_`.  Its not unique. `awk` just look in the array for the hit of `gnl_1046_`. When its found it just return the value stored there.  You need a different approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your $1s aren't unique, you need a count of occurrences of each:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,++f1[$1]]=$0; next} ($1,++f2[$1]) in a{print a[$1,f2[$1]],$0}' file1 file2
gnl_1046_ 10 0.996904 gnl_1046_ 7 4.598512
gnl_1046_ 10 6.904 gnl_1046_ 7 0.4598512
```

Change the FS and/or OFS to tab as you see fit.

Comment: I was just working on this, but yours are better.  Nice solution.

Comment: Ok you are right! Thank you very much! Looks a bit more complicated than I thought..I would really appreciate if you could explain the changes you made. Thanks

Comment: I created a count of occurrences of $1 for each file and added that count as a 2nd index to the array a. It's really very simple and only very slightly different from what you had before so if you understood that then I suspect if you thought about this update for a couple of minutes you'd understand it just fine too. If you're still not clear, add some prints to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

here my awk solution:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{i[$1,FNR]=$0;d[$1];n=FNR;next}
      $1 in d{for(x=1;x<=n;x++)if(i[$1,x]){
           print i[$1,x], $0;delete i[$1,x];break}
       }' file1 file2
```

well I didn't put `<tab>` in the input files, so you can adjust it a bit, with space as sep, the line above outputs:

```
gnl_1046_ 10 0.996904    gnl_1046_ 7 4.598512
gnl_1046_ 10 6.904 gnl_1046_ 7 0.4598512
```

The trick is that I maintained a 2-d array `i(x,y)`, to save lines with same $1 in file1, and after one matched, remove the element with the `i(x, min(y))`

the codes was tested with gawk 4.